# Connection refused to [RequestHttps] action on MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to secure part of my site and want to use HTTPS so packages are encrypted, but when I do that I get

Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Server rejected the connection  <- Translated

```
[HttpGet]
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

If I remove the RequireHttps and dont do Https in my browser I got no issue reaching it

Comment: Did you install a valid certificate on the server?

Comment: Shouldnt it just ask "This is not a valid ssl certificate" and ask if I am sure I want to trust it?

Comment: If the certificate is installed correctly, sure.

Comment: Cant you use https without a certificate? (Like for example a Synology server that uses Https where you get a warning when vising the website)

Comment: I don't think you can. It doesn't have to be trusted (you'll get a warning), but you I'm pretty sure IIS won't serve HTTPS requests with no certificate. It's pretty easy to create [self signed certificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=WS.10).aspx) for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup HTTPS correctly under IIS?  If you are using Cassini I believe that HTTPS is not available.

See here - http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis/

Comment: Its a paid domain, cant I use it without a real ssl certifiate? I am just trying to create a RESTful server, and I want to send json objects from a WP to my web server encrypted (therefor I thought https)

Comment: To run HTTPS you *NEED* SSL, that's the whole point.  If you want a certificate without paying for it you can create a self-signed one there's an option in IIS manager to do this, or you can go to http://cacert.org and get one there.

Comment: I use a paid webhost and they dont sell SSL, and I cant access the IIS manager

Comment: Then unless they offer an option to enable HTTPS you're out of luck.

Comment: They talk about using a SSL proxy, not sure if thats possible to do for free though

Comment: SSL certificates generally aren't free (unless you go to CACert.org, but that requires users to have their root certificate installed as a trusted root).  So I doubt you will be able to do this for free.

Comment: Getting a warning is fine so using a trail is fine, I am just not sure how to implement it without having access to IIS, but I will wait with implementing SSL, have some other pressing issues to solve first